# Given two sets diffeomorphic to the unit ball, are the connected components also diffeomorphic to the unit ball?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $X,Y \subset B(0,1)$ be two subsets of the unit open ball $B(0,1) \subset \mathbb R^n$, **each of them diffeomorphic to** $B(0,1)$. Is there any classification for the intersection $X\cap Y$?

More precisely, is it true that $X\cap Y$ has a **finite number (or at least countable number) of connected components**, each of which is **diffeomorphic** to $B(0,1)$ in $\mathbb R^n$ ?

Just for an example, in dimension $2$, each connected component of $X\cap Y$ would be an open simply connected subset, thus by the Riemann mapping theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem) it will be diffeomorphic to the open unit ball.
Although this result is only in the two-dimensional setting, the starting hypothesis is much weaker then the ones I posed above.

Therefore, my question is in some sense if there is a higher dimensional weak generalisation of such result.

[Edit.] Gae. S. gave an example that showed that the answer to 1 is not true.

Comment: It ceases to be the case in larger dimension. For instance, consider $A=S^2$ (let's stay in $B(0,2)$) in $\Bbb R^3$, call $D_1=\{x\in A\,:\, x_1\ge 0\}$ and $D_2=\{x\in A\,:\, x_1\le 0\}$. Enlarge slightly both, obtaining neighbourhoods $U_i$ of $D_i$, $i=1,2$, both of which may be chosen to be diffeomorphic to the $3$-ball. However, $U_1\cap U_2$ will be the interior of a typical $2$-torus embedded in $\Bbb R^3$, and thus $U_1\cap U_2\simeq S^1\times \Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Yes, thanks @Gae.S. . Do you know if there is any kind of classification saying what are the possibilities for these connected components?

Answer (score 1):

Take a hollow rubber ball in ${\mathbb R}^3$, let the air go out, and press one half of the surface into the hollow of the other half. Including the interior you now have a body which is homeomorphic to $B(0,1)\subset{\mathbb R}^3$, but looks like a cup.

Make a second copy of such a thing.

Now intersect the two rim zones of your "cups". The intersection is a full donut, and is not homeomorphic to $B(0,1)$.